# DXF file conversion

Tags: export, dxf, autocad

I am a new qgis user.  Learning how to georeference .pdfs and .jpgs etc. I have a georeferenced pdf survey plat that I converted into a vector. I am now attempting to convert it into a dxf file so I can import the lines into Autocad - however I am having no such luck.  I am able to convert to dxf but when trying to open in Autocad nothing happens. I dont know if the file is too big (449.5 mb)? Or if I am simply doing something wrong. Would be great if someone could coach me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a heavy file and the routine for creating DXF is not the best. I would say that DXF is a good format to read cad files in QGIS, but not the best option to export information form QGIS.

I am not sure if you have the option to use civil 3D, if yes, then the easiest way is to go for shape files directly and import them, skipping the creation of a dxf.

[image]

I have just read about the plugin ArcGIS for AutoCAD. I have no idea how it works, but my advise is to import in CAD from a GIS format rather export to dxf in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Take your DXF files and in QGIS go to "Project -> Import/Export -> Import layers from DWG/DXF" and voila. You should be able to use your vector geometries in QGIS. Once there, you can export them to other formats (eg. shapefile).